# Custom domain for Google Apps mail doesn’t work

Tags: google-workspace, google-apps-email

I use the free edition of Google Apps to handle mail for one of my domains, say `foo.com`. I have set up a custom subdomain called `mail.foo.com` for the domain users to read their mail at. (That’s a standard Google Apps feature.) Recently this domain stopped working – when I run traceroute on the domain the packets simply get lost somewhere in the Google’s network:

```
10  google-118152-ffm-b7.c.telia.net (213.248.102.234)  25.478 ms  27.971 ms
    google-ic-120086-ffm-b7.c.telia.net (80.239.193.138)  31.644 ms
11  72.14.238.46 (72.14.238.46)  29.284 ms  82.576 ms  24.265 ms
12  * * *
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the problem. In order for the custom URL to work, I had to create a CNAME record for `mail.foo.com`. As my domain hoster’s administration interface only permits me to use an IP address for the CNAME record, I had used the IP address of `ghs.googlehosted.com` at that time. Apparently the address has changed lately, and the old one no longer works. After updating the CNAME record to the new IP address of `ghs.googlehosted.com` the service is back online.

Comment: Are you absolutely sure you cannot use `ghs.googlehosted.com` as the value for the CNAME record? Sounds strange. Some DNS admin GUIs requires you to append a `.` to the end of a value: `ghs.googlehosted.com.`
In the current state, you will be vulnerable the next time Google decides to move `ghs.googlehosted.com` to a new IP address.

Comment: Unfortunately yes, the web interface insists on having a “valid IPv4 address”. It’s not a big deal for me to update if the Google’s machine moves again.

Answer (score 0):

If you didn't change anything on your side recently, then it should not be a problem that you can handle yourself. If the problem persists after a few days, do contact Google and inform them about it using the Google Feedback tool available within the Google Apps domain control panel.